# Почему не работает медиа-запрос?

Tags: html, запрос

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не срабатывает

```
.text_ab{
  margin-top: 45px;
}
```

Хотя все остальные работают как нужно.

Вот еще на всякий случай разметка:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 hdn ctr">
          <div class="wrap_myph">
            <img src="img/im.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-9">
          <div class="txt_ab">
            <span class="txt_im">
              Тут текст
            </span>
            <span class="wid">
              Тут много текста

            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: проверьте отладчик, посмотрите, какой стиль перебивает

Comment: в html - "txt_ab", в css - "text_ab" :)

Comment: ага, заметил, когда запостил сюда лол